# Creating textarea and buttons dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am facing issues with creating a dynamic textarea and 'Add' and 'Edit' buttons for every new paragraph.

DEMO of what I have managed so far:

[image]

The 'Add' button is for creating new paragraphs. The user should see a textarea where they enter the content for new paragraph. The first time they click 'Add' button, the text on the button will change to 'Save', the second time they click 'Save' it should append the paragraph to the div and assign it a unique id, which will be used to reference it with the new 'Add' and 'Edit' buttons.

The 'Edit' button is for editing the paragraph from which the 'Edit' button was clicked. To make the paragraph editable I'm using jquery editable (jeditable). Below are appropriate links to jeditable plugin:

- [plugin documentation](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)
- [jeditable live demo](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html)

[image]

[image]

All the paragraph load from the back-end. Using PHP to load paragraphs:

```
    <div class="paragraphs">
      <?php
      foreach($notes['children'] as $overview) :
        if ($overview['type'] == 'Paragraph') :
        ?>
          <div id="block1">
          <p class='edit1'><?php echo $overview['content']; ?></p>
          <p>
            <?php if (isset($subject) && $subject==true) : ?>
              <div id="para1">
                <p><textarea cols="40" rows="2" id="textarea1"></textarea></p>
                <button id="add1" class="add1 success tiny">Add</button>
                <button id="startEdit1" class="canEdit1 tiny">Edit</button>
              </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
          </p>
          </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
```

The 'Add' and 'Edit' button functionality:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/teachers/js/jquery.jeditable.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var $subject_id = "<?php echo $subject_id ?>";
    var $teacher_id = "<?php echo $teacher_id ?>";

    // Define our elements
    var $lock = false;
    //Make the elements editable
    function makeThingsEditable() {
        $editables.editable({
            emptyMessage : '<em>Please write something...</em>',
            callback : function( data ) {
                $info.hide();
                $info.eq(0).show();
            }
        });
    }

    function ajaxRequest(data, method_url, request_type) {
      $.ajaxSetup({
          beforeSend: function(xhr) {
              xhr.setRequestHeader('HTTP/1.1', '200');
          }
      });

      var eurl = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>edit_flow/" + method_url;
      var params = 'inputJson=' + data; 

      var post = $.ajax({
        type: request_type,
        url: eurl,
        data: params,
        success: function(result) {
          console.log('result: '+result);
          console.log('data: '+params);
        },
        async: false
      });

      //alert(post.responseText);
      return post.responseText;
      console.log(post.responseText);
    }

    // Edit paragraph button
    // Button that toggles the editable feature 
    var i = 1;
    var $editables = $('.edit'+i);
    $('.canEdit'+i).click(function() {
        if( $editables.is(':editable') ) {
            //need to call save action here and pass in updated JSON
            if ($(this).text() == 'Save changes')
            {
              var text = $(".edit"+i).text();

              // ajax request
              var datum = '{"subject_id":'+$subject_id+',"teacher_id":'+$teacher_id+',"editedContent":"'+text+'"}';
              ajaxRequest(datum, 'editNotes', 'POST');  // POST request on editNotes
              ajaxRequest(datum, 'loadNotes', 'GET');  // GET request on loadNotes

              // jquery request
              $.get( "<?php echo base_url(); ?>edit_flow/loadNotes", function( data ) {
                var data = '{"subject_id":'+$subject_id+', "teacher_id":'+$teacher_id+', "editedContent":"'+text+'"}';
                //console.log(data);
                alert( data );
              });
            }

            $editables.editable('destroy');
            this.innerHTML = 'Edit';
            i++;
        } else {
            makeThingsEditable();
            this.innerHTML = 'Save changes';
            // TODO h4kl0rd: make $editables selectable 
        }
    });

    // Add paragraph button

    i = 1;
    $('#textarea'+i).hide();
    $('#add'+i).click(function(){
      if ( $(this).text() == "Add" ) {
        $('#textarea'+i).show();
        $(this).text('Save');
        $('#textarea'+i).focus(function() {
            this.select();
        });
      }
      else if ( $(this).text() == "Save" ) {
        if ($('#textarea'+i).val() == ''){
          alert('Enter something...');
        } else {
          $(this).text("Add");
          $('#textarea'+i).hide();
          var overview = $('#textarea'+i).val();
          i++;
          $('.paragraphs').append('<div id="block'+i+'"><p class="edit'+i+'">'+overview+'</p><div id="para'+i+'"><p><textarea cols="40" rows="2" id="textarea'+i+'"></textarea></p><button id="add'+i+'" class="add'+i+' success tiny">Add</button><button id="startEdit'+i+'" class="canEdit'+i+' tiny">Edit</button></div></div>');
        }
      }
    });


</script>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So... what are the issues?

Comment: Y, i dont see the problem either. If its just about adding elements dynamically, you can either use `.innerHTML` (dirty) or `.append` (clean).

Comment: The issue is once I loop through the textarea and buttons, they display but do not function as required. They should have the same functionality as the first elements.

Comment: I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4kl0rd/s5Bqw/1/), so check it out and let me know what's wrong with my code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

change these:

```
 $('.canEdit'+i).click(function() {
 $('#add'+i).click(function(){
```

to these:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.canEdit'+i, function() {
 $(document).on('click', '#add'+i, function() {
```

What seemed to me is your buttons are dynamic and they can't take direct event binding. So instead you have to delegate the event to the closest static parent which is `$('.paragraphs')` or to `$(document)` itself because it is always available.

So if you are using closest static parent then you have to put your event handlers inside `doc ready` and if you are using `$(document)` then its not needed.

```
$(function(){
    var i = 1;
    var $editables = $('.edit'+i);

    $('.paragraphs').on('click', '.canEdit'+i, function() {
         // all your edit stuff
    });

    $('.paragraphs').on('click', '#add'+i, function() {
         // all your addstuff
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks @jai I will try your way and get back to you

Comment: It still behaves the same with your changes. see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4kl0rd/s5Bqw/1/)